# Grouping on Max date for a Customer Record (multiple tables)

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Morning all!

We have a table showing customers, their warehouses and when their record was last changed.  My task is to find the most recent customer number for a specific warehouse.  Most of these haven't changed but there are quite a few that have.  I have created the below query that works perfectly to find the last amend date for all warehouses in my table.

```
Select
  WHS,
  Max(AMENDT) As MAX_AMENDT
From
  MBC6REVQ
Group By
  WHS
Order By
  WHS,
  Max(Distinct (Select
    Max(MAX_AMENDT)
  From
    MBC6REVQ
  Group By
    MBC6REVQ.WHS
  Fetch First
    1 Rows Only)) Desc
```

The issue I have is I now am required to add the customer number and join to my customer table to retrieve the customer name.  Just adding the CUSNO field results in an error so I have to add CUSNO to the 'group by'.  This gives me multiple records for each warehouse.  My data looks like this:

```
    WHS   AMENDT
    A01   1150101
    A01   1130704
    A02   1141030
    A07   1071101
    A10   1020905
```

..so the query correctly returns:

```
    WHS   AMENDT
    A01   1150101
    A02   1141030
    A07   1071101
    A10   1020905
```

I need to add the CUSNO column because the customer number changed.  My query then looks like:

```
Select
  WHS,
  CUSNO,
  Max(AMENDT) As MAX_AMENDT
From
  MBC6REVQ
Group By
  WHS, CUSNO
Order By
  WHS,
  Max(Distinct (Select
    Max(AMENDT)
  From
    MBC6REVQ
  Group By
    MBC6REVQ.WHS
  Fetch First
    1 Rows Only)) Desc
```

...and returns:

```
    WHS   CUSNO   AMENDT
    A01   1003    1150101
    A01   1056    1130704
    A02   1011    1141030
    A07   1169    1071101
    A10   1012    1020905
```

...when I need to have:

```
    WHS   CUSNO   AMENDT
    A01   1003    1150101
    A02   1011    1141030
    A07   1169    1071101
    A10   1012    1020905
```

Can anyone assist?  This is driving me crazy!!!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know all of the capabilities of db2400, so there may be easier/better ways to handle this if it supports windowed functions for example. That said, this is the most "generic" SQL that I can think of, so it's the most likely to work.

```
SELECT
    T1.WHS,
    T1.CUSNO,
    T1.AMENDT
FROM
    MBC6REVQ T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN MBC6REVQ T2 ON
    T2.WHS = T1.WHS AND
    T2.AMENDT > T1.AMENDT
WHERE
    T2.WHS IS NULL
```

Alternatively, if db2400 supports `NOT EXISTS` and correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT
    T1.WHS,
    T1.CUSNO,
    T1.AMENDT
FROM
    MBC6REVQ T1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            MBC6REVQ T2
        WHERE
            T2.WHS = T1.WHS AND
            T2.AMENDT > T1.AMENDT
    )
```

In either case, you'll need to also decide how you want to handle ties and code appropriately for that.

Comment: Thanks, Tom!  I never considered using T2.AMENDT > T1.AMENDT.  This works perfectly!!!!!!

Comment: DB2 for i supports NOT EXISTS and correlated subqueries...the older DB2/400 did also...at least since I started using it in the v3r6 era IIRC.

Comment: DB2 _does_ support windowing functions, but the i doesn't support (last I knew) using aggregates, and only a subset of the usual windowing functions too.  Still it **does** have rank/row number...